# Uploading to Artifactory fails sometime randomaly

Tags: linux, artifactory, jfrog-cli

As part of my CI/CD part of our pipeline is to upload artifacts to our local Artifactory server for deployment
sometimes randomly this message pops up (estimably week of no-usage) and fails the pipeline

```
09:23:16  [Error] Server response: 401 Unauthorized
09:23:16  {
09:23:16    "errors": [
09:23:16      {
09:23:16        "status": 401,
09:23:16        "message": "Token failed verification: expired"
09:23:16      }
09:23:16    ]
09:23:16  }
09:23:16  [Error] Server response: 401 Unauthorized
09:23:16  {
09:23:16    "errors": [
09:23:16      {
09:23:16        "status": 401,
09:23:16        "message": "Token failed verification: expired"
09:23:16      }
09:23:16    ]
09:23:16  }
```

After I just login to the server and log off it goes back to the normal message:

```
11:07:49  [Info] Searching items to download...
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 2] Downloading Repo/xxx.tar.gz
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 0] Downloading Repo/yyy.tar.gz
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 2] [2]: 206 Partial Content...
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 0] [0]: 206 Partial Content...
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 2] [0]: 206 Partial Content...
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 2] [1]: 206 Partial Content...
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 0] [1]: 206 Partial Content...
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 0] [2]: 206 Partial Content...
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 2] Done downloading.
11:07:49  [Info] [Thread 0] Done downloading.
11:07:49  {
11:07:49    "status": "success",
11:07:49    "totals": {
11:07:49      "success": 2,
11:07:49      "failure": 0
11:07:49    }
11:07:49  }
```

I use API key from our servers to connect to the Artifactory server with jfrog-cli

Any suggestions what might make it happen?

Comment: Are you passing the API Key by flag or using the configuration (jfrog config add)? What is your CLI version?

Comment: tried both ways (in VM with jfrog config add or in Container with configuration file) , jfrog version 2.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Could you please confirm if the issue is specific to the repositories that are a part of NuGet packaging by any chance and also having the anonymous access enabled for the Artifactory instance?

If yes, consider configuring the "Force authentication" for the concerned repository that is a part of this build. This should help in overcoming the reported issue.

Comment: They are part of generic packaging, how do you enable the "Force authentication" in the OSS version (if available)?